# How to close a modal dialog, using a button without any script, which was created using HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have created a modal dialog by following below link

http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/10/css3-modal-window-popups-sliding-forms-with-fancybox-effect/

However I need to add a Cancel button on the modal dialog to close that. could someone help me with that?
**I mean, can I use button to close this? something like**

`<input type="button">`

Comment: Looks like there is already a close button the dialog. If you want to add a button with same functionality, perhaps, you should just add the button and set the class name to that of the existing close button.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a link with href='#close' and style it like the other button.

```
<a class="close" href="#close">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: can I use button to close this? something like <input type="button"> ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you want to put it. I added it as such:

```
    <!-- panel with buttons -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="panel">
            <a href="#login_form" id="login_pop">Log In</a>
            <a href="#join_form" id="join_pop">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="#close" id="cancel">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then modified the css on line 17:

```
    .panel a#login_pop, .panel a#join_pop, .panel a#cancel {
```